# Date formatting using moment

Tags: momentjs

I was playing with moment library in node and was trying to format dates:

```
moment().tz(timezone).format('dddd')
```

This formatting gives me the current day of the week like `'Tuesday'`

Now, I want to format like: `'Tuesday May 2, 2017'`

What will be the best way to format it this way using moment?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use moment [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), in your case you have to use `'dddd MMMM D, YYYY'` where:

- `dddd` stands for the day of the week name
- `MMMM` stands for month's name
- `D` stands for the day of the month
- `YYYY` stands for the four digit year

Here a working sample:

```js
var timezone = 'Europe/Rome';
console.log(moment().tz(timezone).format('dddd MMMM D, YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```